# How to find corresponding value python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So my values look something like this (in csv file):

```
   162,100522,19010101,  -31,    0

   162,100522,19010102,  -13,    0

   162,100522,19010103,   -5,    0

   162,100522,19010104,  -10,    0

   162,100522,19010105,  -18,    0


   162,100522,19010106,  -78,    0

   162,100522,19010107,  -66,    0

   162,100522,19010108,   -6,    0

   162,100522,19010109,   42,    0
```

the 19010101 is the date,  1st of January 1901

and the -31 would be the max or min temperature.

I need to find the dates for the highest and lowest temperature

I tried

```
data["DATE"][data["TX"].max()]
```

but it didnt work... I know I can find the max with data["TX"].max() and min with data["TX"].min(), but how do I find the corresponding date with the max and min temperature? Maybe with enumerate?

Comment: This is pandas, correct?

Comment: perhaps `data[data["TX"] == data["TX"].max()]["DATE"]`

Comment: If you are not using pandas for this project, I suggest that you do.

Comment: If you're using pandas, you can just `df.set_index('DATE').TX.idxmax()` and `df.set_index('DATE').TX.idxmin()`

Comment: how are you pulling this data out of your CSV? We need to know if you're parsing using python csv reader or something like Pandas

Comment: enumerate tag doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: `-31 would be the max or min temperature.` What? How can it be the max OR min? If you meant min, then isn't -78 lower than that?

Comment: yes, it is pandas

Comment: @coldspeed I was just taking the first line as an example, I ment that the variable at that place stands for temperature. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
min_temp = data.loc[data['TX'].idxmin(), 'DATE']
max_temp = data.loc[data['TX'].idxmax(), 'DATE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with slightly different implementation and converts the dates to datetime objects.

```
In [50]: import pandas as pd
In [51]: import io
In [52]: fp = io.StringIO('''   162,100522,19010101,  -31,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010102,  -13,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010103,   -5,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010104,  -10,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010105,  -18,    0
...:
...:
...:    162,100522,19010106,  -78,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010107,  -66,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010108,   -6,    0
...:
...:    162,100522,19010109,   42,    0''')

In [53]: df = pd.read_csv(fp, skipinitialspace=True, names=['A','B','Date','TX','C'])
In [54]: df['DateObj'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d')
In [55]: df['DateObj'][df.TX == df.TX.min()]
Out[55]:
5   1901-01-06
Name: DateObj, dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [56]: df['DateObj'][df.TX == df.TX.max()]
Out[56]:
8   1901-01-09
Name: DateObj, dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [57]: df['Date'][df.TX == df.TX.min()]
Out[57]:
5    19010106
Name: Date, dtype: int64
In [58]: df['Date'][df.TX == df.TX.max()]
Out[58]:
8    19010109
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```